# Поисковые боты не обходят страницы

Tags: javascript, seo

Применяю fetch, отправляю запрос в ответ получаю html код, который вставляю в блок. Метод get...

Использую в качестве постраничной навигации. То есть отправлю запрос на url site.ru/page=1 и site.ru/page=2 и тд. Данные страницы никак не запрещены к индексированию

В яндекс вебмастере, просматривая историю обхода. Не увидел, что поисковый бот хоть раз посещал данные страницы.

В чем тут дело, как выполнить используя метод ajax. Так чтобы те страницы содержимое которых подгружаем метод ajax. Чтобы поисковый робот и их тоже обходил. Не с целью индексирования данных страниц, а с той целью чтобы уже на подгруженной странице переходил по внутренним ссылкам и индексировал непосредственно сами публикации сайта.??

Comment: На странице должны быть именно ссылки (не кнопки, которые внутри js отправляют ajax и обновляют страницу)

Comment: Или подключена метрика к вебмастеру, тогда если метрика засечет переход по ссылке напрямую, то информация будет передана в вебмастер и робот будет индексировать страницу. Но опять же, на эту страницу должен попасть пользователь, кнопка без ссылки + ajax тут не прокатят.

Comment: Кнопки никакой нету. Контент в блок добавляется автоматом. Контент добавляется в блок с уже со свежими ссылками. Вопрос в том, видит ли робот подобные ссылки которые были добавлены в блок путем ajax. Да, подключена метрика, обход по счетчику. Но как я понимаю, это просто дает сигнал ботам о новых страницах, она не отменяет обход страниц по умолчанию.

Comment: В истории вебмастер, точно вижу, что робот не обходит постраничную навигацию. Возможно стоит попробовать менять url при подгрузке контента со новой страницы. Возможно так роботы будет отслеживать подобные url и в дальнейшем обходит страницы?

Comment: Ну вообще робот должен сам ссылки собрать сначала, а потом по ним пройтись. Если ссылки висят, но переход для пользователя через ajax, то это не должно роботу мешать. Думаю, Вам лучше обратиться в тех.поддержку яндекса, они точнее скажут, в чём проблема.